# Discoloration of raster edges on export with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster tint that looks like this in QGIS:

[image]

But after exporting as an image through composer the edges look quite different:

[image]

The raster is originally a TIF, and I've tried exporting to JPG and PNG through QGIS composer. I'm guessing that the values are being changed on the export/conversion, but I don't know why.

Can someone please explain what is going on and how I can prevent it?